# PHP MVC - return call_user_func_array() in a __construct

Tags: php

I am working on a MVC site, but I have a problem. I can not return anything from my controllers. I can do things like `$this->someMethod()` but not `return "hello"` I think it has to do with  `call_user_func_array()` So how do I fix this?

## My code:

Router:

```
Class App
{

protected $controller = 'home';
protected $method = 'index';
protected $parameters = [];

public function __construct()
{
    $url = $this->Url();

    if(file_exists('../app/controllers/'. $url[0] .'.php')){

        $this->controller = $url[0];
        unset($url[0]);
    }

    require_once '../app/controllers/'. $this->controller .'.php';

    $this->controller = new $this->controller;

    if (isset($url[1])){
        if (method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])){
            $this->method = $url[1];
            unset($url[1]);
        }
    }

    $this->parameters = $url ? array_values($url) : [''];

    call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->parameters);

}

public function Url()
{
    if(isset($_GET['url'])){
        $url = filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $exploded_url = explode('/', $url);
        return $exploded_url;
    }
}
}
```

Public Index.php:

```
<?php

    require_once '../app/core/init.php';

    $app = new App;
```

A controller:

```
class Home extends Controller
{
public function index($name)
{
    //this works.
    $this->view('index');
    
    //this does not work.
    
    return "hello";

    }
}
```

So how do I solve it, so the `return` works too?

Comment: Which framework are you using??...and please do not respond with `my own framework`!

Comment: @Hackerman: It's the Luuk777w framework.

Comment: You have all the code you need to answer your own problem I think. Your Router class makes the call to call_user_func_array and this is where the value would be returned. If you wanted to do something with the return value, that would be the place. Are you sure you really mean "return" a value? Or do you mean output a value?

Comment: Where are you attempting to use the returned value???

Comment: @Hackerman Its for a school project, and they do not allow the use of frameworks for this project. So I HAVE TO make my own

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, I tried but it won't return anything, But I do get the value when I do a `var_dump` on `call_user_func_array()`

Comment: @S.Imp Hmmm... I think outputting then, but I tried echoing it what did not work, so I tried returning it. But How could I output it then?

Comment: You can capture the return of the function by assigning the result of the `call_user_func_array()` to a variable or echoing it, however you CAN NOT return anything from a constructor when it is called upon instantiating an object.

Comment: Hmmmmm.... thats weird, echoing works... I swear it did not work before..... i'm really confused now :/